# setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment not having any effect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been trying for a while to move the back button on iOS 7 down a little bit.

I'm putting it un using this code

```
UIImage *barBackBtnImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-back-arrow.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];     
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:barBackBtnImg];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:barBackBtnImg];
```

and trying to move it down about 20px or so using this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-50.f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But this does'nt seem to move it. Anyone have similar problems?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, just wondered what you did in the end as I don't fully understand the answer you accepted below.

Comment: I second that, the chosen answer doesn't make a lot of sense. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use a same image set on 0,0,320,20 size then status bar show the image background 
and another thing to u hide the status bar
us

code is

`UIImage *img_st = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];`

`UIImageView *img_status = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img_st];`

`[self.view addSubview:img_status];`

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:img_status];`

`img_status.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);`

`[img_status release];`